# XSLT element loop

Tags: xslt

My XSLT is like

```
<!DOCTYPE stylesheet [
<!ENTITY hyphen "<xsl:text>-</xsl:text>">
<!ENTITY cr "<xsl:text>
</xsl:text>">
]>

<xsl:stylesheet id="test" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
exclude-result-prefixes="ext"
version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="vc_NDCROI" select="'NDC05'" />

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="mPass2">
     <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="mPass2"/>
     </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1Result">
        &cr;
        <xsl:comment>ACS&amp;T
            Receipt Confirmation
            </xsl:comment>
            &cr;
            <xsl:element name="Batch">
            <xsl:element name="ASN">
            <xsl:for-each
            select="dcsextractdata/dataheaders/dataheader[record_type = 'ORH']">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="orh_receipt" />
            </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>

    </xsl:element>
            </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:apply-templates mode="mPass2"
                    select="ext:node-set($vrtfPass1Result)/*" />
                        </xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="/*[local-name()='Batch']" mode="mPass2">
    &cr;
            <Batch xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                                     <xsl:copy-of select="node()|@*"/>
                                             </Batch>
                                                  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dataheader" mode="orh_receipt">

<xsl:element name="BatchReferences">
    <xsl:element name="SenderCode"><xsl:value-of select="site_user_def_type_7"/></xsl:element>

    <xsl:element name="ReceiverCode"><xsl:value-of select="client_user_def_type_7" /> </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>  

<xsl:element name="Supplier">
    <xsl:element name="EanCode"><xsl:value-of select="client_name" /> </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>

<xsl:element name="Customer">
<xsl:element name="EanCode"></xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="EDI1Code"></xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="EDI2Code"></xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="EDI3Code"></xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="EDI4Code"></xsl:element>
</xsl:element>

<xsl:element name="Consignee">
    <xsl:element name="EanCode"><xsl:value-of select="add_user_def_type_1" /> </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>

<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="user_def_chk_1 != 'Y'">
<xsl:element name="Consignor">
    <xsl:element name="EanCode"></xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise> 
<xsl:element name="Consignor">
    <xsl:element name="EanCode">5060133990239</xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>  
</xsl:otherwise>        
</xsl:choose>

<xsl:element name="DeliverFrom">
    <xsl:element name="EanCode"></xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>

<xsl:element name="DeliverTo">
    <xsl:element name="EanCode"><xsl:value-of select="add_user_def_type_1" /> </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>  

<xsl:element name="DocumentNumber"><xsl:value-of select="user_def_type_1" /> </xsl:element>


<xsl:element name="DocumentDate"><xsl:value-of select="creation_date" /> </xsl:element>


<xsl:element name="ShippingDate"><xsl:value-of select="creation_date" /> </xsl:element>


<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="user_def_chk_1 != 'Y'">
<xsl:element name="Carrier">
    <xsl:element name="SuppliersCode"></xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:when>                                                                    
<xsl:otherwise> 
<xsl:element name="Carrier">
    <xsl:element name="SuppliersCode">5060133990239</xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>  
</xsl:otherwise>        
</xsl:choose>           

<xsl:element name="OrderNumber">
    <xsl:element name="Customers"><xsl:value-of select="order_id" /> </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>  

<xsl:element name="OrderDate">
    <xsl:element name="Customers"><xsl:value-of select="order_date" /> </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>

<xsl:element name="ShipmentNumber"><xsl:value-of select="user_def_type_2" /> </xsl:element>

<xsl:element name="PickListNumber"><xsl:value-of select="user_def_type_3" /> </xsl:element>


<xsl:element name="Package">
<xsl:element name="Markings">
    <xsl:element name="Barcode"><xsl:value-of select="user_def_type_1" /> </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>

        </xsl:element>
<xsl:for-each select="datalines/dataline[record_type = 'ORL']" >
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="lines" />
                                        </xsl:for-each>



<xsl:template match="dataline" mode="lines">
    <xsl:element name="Product">

    <xsl:element name="LineNumber"><xsl:value-of select="user_def_num_1" /> </xsl:element>

    <xsl:element name="EANCode"><xsl:value-of select="ean" /> </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="SuppliersCode"><xsl:value-of select="sku_id" /> </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="Quantity">
    <xsl:element name="Amount"><xsl:value-of select="qty_shipped" /> </xsl:element> 
    </xsl:element>  
    <xsl:element name="CreationDate">0001-01-01</xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="ExpiresDate"></xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="CustomerPalStatus"><xsl:value-of select="condition_id" /> </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="Markings">
    <xsl:element name="Barcode"><xsl:value-of select="batch_id" /> </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="InitialPalletQty"></xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="Batch"><xsl:value-of select="batch_id" /> </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>



</xsl:template>

</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have loop for lines , I have  package tag starting from  before marking tag and right now package tag is closing after marking tag  but should be close after product tag and before ASN close tag.Please help.

Comment: Please format your code properly. Also, please shrink it down to the minimum amount necessary to show the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand your schema.

Currently, ASN tag opens and closes at top, Package opens and closes towards bottom (wrapped around Markings), and Product opens and closes at the very bottom.

For Package to close after Product and before ASN, requires ASN to be wrapped around Package and Product. And Package wrapped around Product.

So move `<xsl:element name = ...>` and corresponding `</xsl:element>` tags around to the needed hierarchy:

```
<xsl:element name="ASN">
   ...
   <xsl:element name="Package">
       ...
       <xsl:element name="Product"> 
       ...  
       </xsl:element>  <!-- Product's closing -->
   </xsl:element>  <!-- Package's closing -->  
</xsl:element>  <!-- ASN's closing -->

</xsl:template>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I tried that but in that case  i have improved like   having package start by  <xsl:element name="Package"> before marking and end before second last </xsl:template> but it gives the error . As i need the package start before marking only

Comment: I need package start before marking only and end before before ASN close tag.

Comment: In [XML syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp), elements must have closing tags and must be properly nested. Do not move closing tags between `</xsl:template>` but between `</xsl:element>`. I updated accordingly. And due to syntax rules, ASN must wrap around Package in order for Package to close within it. So as my answer mentioned, move closing element tags for Package and ASN to the end but before template close.

Comment: Thanks for reply,I did like <xsl:element name="Package">
<xsl:element name="Markings"> .................................
 </xsl:element>
 </xsl:element>
 </xsl:element>
 </xsl:element>
 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:template> But getting error like (Location of error unknown)XSLT Error

Comment: Getting the error like The element type "xsl:template" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</xsl:template>".

Comment: This seems to suggest an element is not closing. Did you remove the previous ASN tag from top to bottom? No need to add any closing tags for ASN or Product -just move their positions.